# The scope of a tempory object in a function call

Tags: c++

In the following code, temporary string object is created and destroyed after returning its internal buffer. Therefore `p` points to an invalid memory location.

```
int main()
{
    const char* p = std::string("testing").c_str();
    //p points to an invalid memory location
}
```

In the following code, temporary string object is created. When is the tempory string object get deleted? After or before executing `func()`? Can I safely use the p pointer inside the `func()` method?

```
void func(const char* p)
{
    //p is valid or invalid ????
}

int main()
{
    func(std::string("testing").c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is valid until immediately after the statement `func(std::string("testing").c_str());`. That means that the anonymous temporary string is not popped from the stack until after `func` has returned.

So your code is completely safe.

Comment: is there any reference for that?